# How to create global user event listener in windows phone?

Tags: events, user-input, windows-phone

I want to create a small app that suggests me where to paste the contents of clipboard (mostly from email to calendar or search).

How can I create a listener/hook that fires when the content of clipboard is changed? For example: Create toast when [Clipboard.ContainsText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ms597026%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) changes.

Note that I do not need to know the contents of the clipboard. Alternatives for this would be would be hooks to "copy", "selection change" or any of the global gesture or click events.

Answer (score 0):

There is no clipboard event that I'm aware of. Your best bet would be to create a long press event that checks the contents of the clipboard and compares it to the previous clipboard content, which you would have to store yourself.